# Zend Framework Include Path

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying just to use Zend Library on my current project, without setting php.ini's

```
include_path(.....)
```

In my index.php i initialized

```
set_include_path('library');
```

Where is stored Zend library.
Folder structure is following

```
-site_folder
    -other_folders
    -...
    -library
         -Zend
    -index.php
```

Then i proceed to initialize an Adapter

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
    ));

... other code

}
```

And following error appears:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\site_folder\index.php on line 59
```

To solve this question i include in my index.php

```
require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Adapter.php';
```

Then other fatal error appears:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootSite\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter.php on line 19
```

To solve this error i need to include

```
require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/AdapterInterface.php';
```

But then arise another error an so on. How can i just related everything to my index.php? Without using Zend Skeleton Apllication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the autoloader so that PHP will include the classes on demand for you. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html#manual-configuration

Alternatively, you could install ZF using Composer, which would take care of this for you.

Comment: where to find "Phly" and "Scapi" which are declared in Manual ConfiguratioN?

Comment: Those are just examples of how you setup autoloading for third party libraries. You only need lines 4, 5 and 18 from that code example.